# PHP REGEX - removal of excess line breaks - String Manipulation Issue

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, line-breaks

I am inputting a dirty string (lots of spaces, line-breaks and extra false spaces just before punctuation characters.

my desired output is explained in the code below.

It seems that I can achieve to remove excess white-spaces + to remove spaces just before punctuation characters. **But my output has still unwanted excess line-breaks.**

I use functions below while I print the user input from MySQL db to screen.

```
echo "\t\t".'<p>'.nl2br(convert_str(htmlspecialchars($comment))).'</p>'."\r\n";
```

my custom function code is below:

```
function convert_str ($str)
{
    // remove excess whitespace
    // looks for a one or more spaces and replaces them all with a single space.
    $str = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $str);
    // check for instances of more than two line breaks in a row
    // and then change them to a total of two line breaks
    //did not worked for me --> preg_replace('/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\n\n", $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', preg_replace('/\s*$^\s*/m', "\n", $str));
    // if exists; remove 1 space character just before punctuations below:
    // $punc = array('.',',',';',':','...','?','!','-','—','/','\\','“','”','‘','’','"','\'','(',')','[',']','’','{','}','*','&','#','^','<','>','|');
    $punc = array(' .',' ,',' ;',' :',' ...',' ?',' !',' -',' —',' /',' \\',' “',' ”',' ‘',' ’',' "',' \'',' (',' )',' [',' ]',' ’',' {',' }',' *',' &',' #',' ^',' <',' >',' |');
    $replace = array('.',',',';',':','...','?','!','-','—','/','\\','“','”','‘','’','"','\'','(',')','[',']','’','{','}','*','&','#','^','<','>','|');
    $str = str_replace($punc,$replace,$str);
    return $str;
}
```

Can you please correct me?

update: I use prepared statements to enter user input into MySQL db tables and I do not manipulate users' data during entrance into db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the simple but 5-hours-consuming reason: using just `\n` instead of `\r\n`.

So the code that satisfies my requirements is:

```
function convert_str ($str)
{
    // remove excess whitespace
    // looks for a one or more spaces and replaces them all with a single space.
    $str = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $str);
    // check for instances of more than two line breaks in a row
    // and then change them to a total of two line breaks
    $str = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\r\n\r\n", $str);
    // if exists; remove 1 space character just before punctuations below:
    // $punc = array('.',',',';',':','...','?','!','-','—','/','\\','“','”','‘','’','"','\'','(',')','[',']','’','{','}','*','&','#','^','<','>','|');
    $punc = array(' .',' ,',' ;',' :',' ...',' ?',' !',' -',' —',' /',' \\',' “',' ”',' ‘',' ’',' "',' \'',' (',' )',' [',' ]',' ’',' {',' }',' *',' &',' #',' ^',' <',' >',' |');
    $replace = array('.',',',';',':','...','?','!','-','—','/','\\','“','”','‘','’','"','\'','(',')','[',']','’','{','}','*','&','#','^','<','>','|');
    $str = str_replace($punc,$replace,$str);
    return $str;
}
```